# Source code does not match the byte code android studio

Tags: java, android, debugging, firebase, crash

Below is my code snippet. This code worked once, when i created the listadapter first time. But sometime after it is not working. The app keeps crashing when it hits list.add in the below snippet.

```
public class ViewRequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

DatabaseReference databaseRequests;
private TextView textViewRequestNo;
private EditText editTextRequestPurpose;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_request);        databaseRequests = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Requests");
    Query query = databaseRequests.orderByChild("requestNo").equalTo(11);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String requestDate = (String) messageSnapshot.child("requestDate").getValue();
                String requestPurpose = (String) messageSnapshot.child("requestPurpose").getValue();
                String requestConPerson = (String) messageSnapshot.child("requestConPerson").getValue();
                String requestSepList = (String) messageSnapshot.child("requestSepList").getValue();
                //populateRequests(requestDate,requestPurpose,requestConPerson,requestSepList);

                HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN,requestDate);
                temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN,requestPurpose);
                temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN,requestConPerson);
                temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN,requestSepList);
                list.add(temp);
                ListViewAdapter adapter= new ListViewAdapter(ViewRequestActivity.this,list);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
```

Initially i tried with 
//populateRequests(requestDate,requestPurpose,requestConPerson,requestSepList);
function call and listview will populate all the values properly

I dont know something happened after which, while debugging the app using adb to mobile it always crashes going inside looper.java when it hits this line "**list.add(temp);**" saying the "source code does not match the byte code".

For this i have also disabled instant run

looper.java as below

```
 final long newIdent = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
        if (ident != newIdent) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Thread identity changed from 0x"
                    + Long.toHexString(ident) + " to 0x"
                    + Long.toHexString(newIdent) + " while dispatching to "
                    + msg.target.getClass().getName() + " "
                    + msg.callback + " what=" + msg.what);
        }

        msg.recycleUnchecked();
    }
}
```

I tried debugging a lot, but not sure it always crashes.? 
I hope someone would provide a light on what I am missing.

Comment: clean the project and disable instant run then try again

Comment: I have cleaned a lot of times. Also disabled instant run.And rebbuild the project but still the sam.e